# NameError: name 'sess' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running python program under tensorflow. When I input sess.run(),the command line prompt me that NameError: name 'sess' is not defined

```
print(sess.run(W_conv1))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-cf7d3892efbb>", line 1, in <module>
    print(sess.run(W_conv1))

NameError: name 'sess' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you define `sess = tf.Session()` somewhere? Or, equivalently, did you put that print inside a `with tf.Session() as sess:` block?

Comment: Thank you.I check my program and find that 'sess' is not defined before sess.run().I add the defination,and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define `sess`. Put this line before accessing it.

`sess = tf.Session()`

or even you could use a `with` statement:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    #Do something with sess
    print(sess.run(W_conv1))
```